# Query execute in N+1 times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

In my application i am using

```
phy = Physician.find(:all, :include => {:clinician_affiliations => :provider_organization}, :with_disabled => true).select{|physician| not physician.provider_organizations.blank? }.collect{|enum| [enum.display_name_schedule, enum.id]}
```

code. When i run the code it executes N+1 times. I am sure this is the problem of N+1 query in rails. I need to simplify this code with out N+1.

Note : clinician_affiliation is belongs to provider_organization. (I am using Rails 2.3)

```
class Clinician
.....
has_many :provider_organizations, :through => :clinician_affiliations
...
end
```

From DB Physician and Provider_organizations are types of party table.

> class Physician < Clinician

Comment: What is the relation between Physician and provider_organization ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work

```
Physician.find(:all, :include => :provider_organizations)
```

Comment: Pls, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806038/spliting-large-statement-into-subpart this