# Rails splited code not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using rails 2.3. In my application it uses

```
val =  Party.find(:all, :conditions => [" type in ('Physician') || id in (?)",PartyLabel.find(:all,:conditions=>"label_id=#{Label.find_by_label("Can Schedule").id}").collect{|p| p.party_id if Party.find(p.party_id).respond_to?("provider_organizations")}], :with_disabled => true).select{|physician| not physician.provider_organizations.blank? }.collect{|enum| [enum.display_name_schedule, enum.id]}
```

code to achieve some requirements. Now i wants to split the code in to 2 parts.

```
1. phys = Physician.find(:all, :include => :provider_organizations, :with_disabled => true).select{|physician| not physician.provider_organizations.blank? }.collect{|enum| [enum.display_name_schedule, enum.id]}
```

it's working fine.. and the second part will be

```
2. sch = Party.find(:all, :include => [:as_labels], :conditions => {:label => {:label => "Can Schedule"}}.respond_to?("provider_organizations")).select{|physician| not physician.provider_organizations.blank? }.collect{|enum| [enum.display_name_schedule, enum.id]}
```

it shows `NoMethodError (undefined method 'provider_organizations' for #<ProviderOrganization:0x1ab81c20>):` error message... Any comments could be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `respond_to?("provider_organizations")` is called for a wrong object. Here is your code #2:

```
sch = Party.find(
  :all,
  :include => [:as_labels],
  :conditions => {
    :label => {
      :label => "Can Schedule"
    }
  }.respond_to?("provider_organizations")  # What's this ???
).select{ |physician|
  not physician.provider_organizations.blank?
}.collect{ |enum|
  [enum.display_name_schedule, enum.id]
}
```

If I understand it correctly, the `respond_to?` should be inside the `select`:

```
...
).select{ |physician|
  physician.respond_to?("provider_organizations") && not physician.provider_organizations.blank?
}.collect{ ...
```